# Do I have to open the cursor to be able to use %FOUND or %NOTFOUND cursor attributes for an implicit cursor?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g, database-cursor

Is it possible to execute `c_emp%notfound` after the following FOR loop or do I have to open the cursor first?

```
declare
 cursor c_emp is select * from employee;
 begin
    for c_rec in c_emp
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line(r_emp.first_Name);
    end loop;
 end;
 /
```

I want to execute a statement a single UPDATE statement after the FOR loop but only if the FOR loop did process any of the rows on the cursor. I know i can set a flag but is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "Is it possible to execute c_emp%notfound after the following FOR
>   loop"

No, that's going to hurl `ORA-01001: invalid cursor`.  The cursor attributes only have scope while the cursor is open, which in this syntax is between the `FOR` and the `END LOOP`.

This is an ugly aspect of PL/SQL but I'm afraid you're stuck with a count.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just:

```
declare
 cursor c_emp is select * from employee;

 begin

    for c_rec in c_emp
    loop
       dbms_output.put_line(r_emp.first_Name);
    end loop;

    UPDATE some_table
       SET some_values
     WHERE some_conditions
       AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM employee WHERE r.id IS NOT NULL)
 end;
 /
```

I assume here the your employee table has a primary key called ID, you can adjust as needed.